# Overriding an OnSelectedItemListener in a Spinner

Tags: android, android-widget

So I have this code:

```
converteeUnit.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
       int arg2, long arg3) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub   
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }
}) ;
```

I am trying change this but I do not understand the parameters for the `OnItemSelected` method. What does each one mean and what would I need specifically to implement spinner called convertedUnit, for this example? Also how could I have it do the same thing as before while I also insert my desired code?

Comment: what you means by `I am trying to change this`

Comment: Sorry I mean the onItemSelected Method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt, always [check the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html#onItemSelected%28android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29).

- AdapterView = Spinner
- View = view that was selected (in the
  dialog/dropdown)
- int = position which was pressed
- long = id (probably
  not useful to you)

Not sure what you're trying to do, but in general you want to use the `position` to get the value from the `Adapter` you used to populate the Spinner. You can always use `spinner.getAdapter().getItem(position)`

Comment: I will check to see if this does it. I am basically trying to make editTexts appear if the spinner is on the item that will need more EditText Inputs.

Comment: My main confusion is whether that AdapterView is actually the spinner and I only need to add my code or do I need to declare it as such?

Comment: AdapterView will indeed be `converteeUnit`

Comment: Yea. I have a final project due at 1700 today and I was really panicking and getting worried about this functionality for my program. What I am doing is changing the number of ExitTexts for input for the unit Deg/Min/Sec. I put them in the XML but had there visibility "GONE" until I needed them so that is why I needed to use this listener. Thanks for your help! You are a lifesaver!